# Wordpress: Copy only data (uploads, pages and posts)

Tags: php, database, wordpress, copy

Found only and many solutions to copy/backup a WHOLE Wordpress installation but that is not what i'm looking for.

I want to rebuild (setup from scratch) an existing Wordpress installation (it's a real mess) without the bulky plugins, themes and other settings. Just only uploads, pages and posts.

Because the SQL contains many relations and tables, I want exactly to know which tables I must overwrite without damaging current installation. Maybe there is a tool around to achieve this?

This can reduce the amount of time needed to copy all data intensively.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you looked at tools > export ? This allows you to export posts etc and when you import in your new location you can also import the uploads associated with those posts

Comment: Ah, thanks, take a look at it! Just installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/, is it good?

Comment: Could you post what tables you have in the DB? I'll give some guidance in an answer below but can modify more specifically for you with some insight into your DB.

Answer (score 0):

General pointers:

- Most of the data you want is probably in the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables - and if you want to keep the comments `wp_comments` and `wp_commentmeta` would be key. `wp_options` and `wp_term` tables are also important for option and taxonomy information.
- WordPress has fairly semantic table names (ie `wp_terms`, `wp_comments`, etc) so one thing to check for in the DB are lots of extraneous tables named something similar to your plugin. You can probably drop those.
- Check over `wp_comments` and `wp_users` - if the site ever had a spam problem, these will get larded up.
- WordPress plugins and themes are usually off in their own little worlds, acting as separate applications that hook into the WordPress app when it gets instantiated. Before importing into the new site, disable all the plugins/themes on the old one. I think you'll find most of the content isn't effected (if the site was built using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com), you need to leave that one in though).